# QnA Maker excel file

Tags: azure-qna-maker

Does anyone know how to add or separate two questions to one answer in excel?
example:

Question:
elementary school name, primary school name, school name

Answer:
Critobal Columbus

Comment: You can use a new row for each question and use -exactly- the same answer for each.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple questions with identical answers, it will group them together in the KB.

So it would look like:

Q: elementary school name

A: Critobal Columbus

Q: primary school name

A: Critobal Columbus

Q: school name

A: Critobal Columbus

Obviously this is not an ideal way to do this, but it has already been submitted as a suggestion for how to improve QnA Maker:
https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/578689-qna-maker-api/suggestions/34751899-qna-maker-excel-file-add-more-questions-to-one-an